# I want to show data monthwise in one sql query? Is it possible in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a one database and saved one year data. I want to access all data in monthwise. like (01-01-2017-01-30-2017). My column type **Datetime**

```
date_table
01-01-2016
01-02-2016
02-02-2017
.....
.....
```

I Want to show

```
date_table                       count
01-01-2016 to 30-01-2016         5
01-02-2016 t0 28-02-2016         10
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: I take datetime data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql's built in function `LAST_DAY`, like this:

Just replace here "t", with your table name

```
SELECT CONCAT( CONCAT(mnth, '-01'), ' to ', LAST_DAY(CONCAT(mnth, '-01')) ) AS date_table, cnt FROM (
    select substr(cast(date_table as CHAR), 1, 7) AS mnth, count(*) AS cnt from    t
    group by substr(cast(date_table as CHAR), 1, 7)
) outertable
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(ASSIGNEDTO) AS TC,
CONCAT(Round(count(case when STATUS = 'CLOSED' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1)),'%') as SC,
Round(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE))/480) as WH,
ROUND((126720-sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE)))/480) as VH,
CONCAT(ROUND(COUNT(Feedback_Rate)/COUNT(Assignedto)*100,'%'),'%') as Feed_Percent,
Round(SUM(Feedback_Rate)/(count(Feedback_Rate)*5)*5,1) as AVG_Feedback,

FROM `it_service_ticket`
group BY assignedto;

Answer (score 1):

Have a derived table that returns the year and month. `GROUP BY` its result and count:

```
select y, m, count(*)
from
(
    select year(date_column) y , month(date_column) m
    from tablename
)
group by y, m
```

I don't know MySQL very well, so you'll have to format the output by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your Date is of type `DateTime` in SQL-Server

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,TimeStamp) AS [MONTH]
                , DATEPART(YY,TimeStamp) [YEAR]     
                , SUM(*) Count
FROM Table
WHERE TimeStamp IS NOT NULL             
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,TimeStamp), DATEPART(YY,TimeStamp)
```

Result would be like this

```
MONTH   YEAR    Count
December2015    237
October 2015    51
August  2016    0
January 2016    9
March   2016    160
```